# Box2D - Resetting collision detection for bodies already intersecting

Tags: c++, box2d, cocos2d-x

I have bodies flying through the world. Some are overlapping as sensors. Then, when I need them to, some need to change state and detect any collision between the current and other bodies. The problem is that if they are already intersecting, the engine doesn't recheck for collision. Is there a way to flag a body for a recheck or something like that when the state change happens.

Comment: you should always allow all of the possible contact events to happen and decide based on your state whether and how to handle the contact event

Comment: @LearnCocos2D That doesn't answer my question at all. Imagine I have two bodies floating around one called water and fire. They are both initially water. When I switch one to fire, they are overlapping so the collision handler has already fired. Now one is water and one is fire but it hasn't detected that because they were already overlapping. is there a way I can flag them to recalculate, like a dirty flag or a refresh flag so that even if they have already begun contact, when the type changes, the collision is recalculated.

Comment: In each fixture, keep a list of the other fixtures it is touching. Update the list when you get begin/end contact events.